# Mathematical Notation Regarding Domain and Range

Tags: functions, notation

When I see "$f\colon A \rightarrow B$" does this mean (a), or does this mean (b), where:

(a) There is a function f with domain (all of) A and range (all of) B.

(b) There is a function f with domain that is a subset of A and range that is a subset of B.

Comment: or (c) $f$ has domain (all of) $A$ and image that is a subset of $B$

Comment: True. Is that how you read f: A-> B?

Comment: @JoshG I read that as "function $f$ from $A$ to $B$". It is implicitly understood that the range is a subset of the codomain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f:A$$ \to$$B$ means there is a function with name $f$ with domain $A$.

Now everytime it's domain is whole $A$ when it is defined that f goes from $A$ to $B$ .

it's **Codomain** is $B$ .Codomain and range is different .The set $f(A)$ is the **range** of $f$.but it is not always equal to $B$ .when they are equal then the function is called **surjective**.

Comment: In other words, the notation means that the domain is all of A, and the range is a subset of B. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoshG Yeah, **RANGE** $ \subseteq$ **CODOMAIN**